# Best way to distribute Excel spreadsheet with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, distribution

I am trying to find out how to distribute an excel file on the net in such a way that most users will be able to use it.  I am aware of the Microsoft Excel Viewer (which can open Excel files without having Office installed), but it doesn't run VBA code, which is a necessity for this file.  Moreover, there are some changes to the API in Office 2007 which make some parts of the file render incorrectly, so I would also prefer that the solution is applicable to Excel XP / 2003.  Does anyone have any hints / tips on the different possible ways to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If VBA is a must then there really is no alternative to having the full client installed.

Pray to the FSM for Google to add scripting to Google Docs more quickly?

Comment: Yes, this is certainly what I was worried about. Oh well, I suppose I will just have to tell users to make sure that they have excel installed.

Answer (score 2):

Excel is the only application which runs Excel VBA code.

[SpreadsheetGear for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) is an Excel compatible spreadsheet component for .NET which includes a [Windows Forms spreadsheet control](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/windowsforms.aspx) and an API which is similar to Excel. With SpreadsheetGear, you have the advantage of more control and you don't have to worry about whether your user has Excel, but the downside is that you would have to rewrite your VBA code in VB.NET or C#.

You can download a free trial [here](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/downloads/register.aspx) if you want to try it out.

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC

Answer (score 0):

Make it a Excel Add-In and add password protection.

[How to created Excel Add-In](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/excel-add-in-create.htm)

Comment: How will the users who don't have Excel installed use an add-in?